# I can't return json from Laravel 5.5 Validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, laravel-5.5

I have a Laravel API endpoint to store events.

I added this method inside the [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests): `StoreEventRequest` to improve error responses:

```
/**
 * Reformat Errors.
 *
 * @param Validator $validator
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    if ($this->wantsJson()) {
        $messages = reformatMessages($validator->messages());
        dd($messages); // If I do this I can see the messages, otherwise response is blank.
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $messages
        ]);
    }

    return $validator->messages()->toArray();
}
```

However, if there's a missing param response is blank. If I `dd` I can see the messages nicely formatted but nothing comes back from `return`.

I'm testing on Postman.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
protected function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    if ($this->wantsJson()) {
        $messages = reformatMessages($validator->messages());
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($messages, 422));
    }

    return $validator->messages()->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding http response code as the second parameter to the function call?,

```
return response()->json([
     'success' => false,
     'message' => $messages

], 400); // 400 is the response code
```